# how to change label to bold when a select element has focus - JQuery

Tags: jquery, select, input, focus

On the label last name , the label don't change to bold when the focus is on the 2nd select element. any tips on how to do this,

I've got this code

```
<form id="formul">
  <label for="a1">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="a1" class="_lblbold"><br>
  <label for="a2">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="a2" class="_lblbold">
  <select id="a2"><option value="">Choose</option></select>
  <select id="a3"><option value="">Choose</option></select><br>
  <label className="col-md-5 lbl_e2bnames" For="id_input_addit">Additional</label>
  <textarea id="id_input_addit" cols="50" rows="7" placeholder="ABCD"></textarea><br>
</form>
```

Jquery

```
$('form :input').bind({
    focus: function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id').toString();
        var add = $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").addClass('labelfocus');
      $("label[]").addClass('labelfocus');


    },
    blur: function () {
        $('label').removeClass('labelfocus');
      $("label").removeClass('labelfocus');
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.labelfocus {
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Here's the Codepen : http://codepen.io/parlop/pen/oxOoba

Answer (score 2):

based on your logic the problem is that the second element is using another ID

```
<select id="a3"><option value="">Choose</option></select><br>
```

change that for "a2"

conceptually is wrong use 2 or more elements with the same ID, in that case you can use classes instead of use the same ID